# Плагин uploadify

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Всем привет. 
Пользуюсь плагином  uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) для мультизагрузки фотографий на сервер.
В серверной части uploadify.php мне необходимо получать номер текущего загружаемого файла.
Просто номер по порядку 1,2,3 и т.д. Хочу использовать его в имени будущего файла. Уверен, что этот номер можно сгенерить в файле плагина jquery.uploadify.js и передавать его каждый раз увеличивая на единицу при вызове uploadify.php. А вот где вызывается uploadify.php в плагине я не нашел. Прошу помощи.
Как передавать этот номер?

Comment: Непонятно вот что: как определять номер? Мы можем загружать файлы по очереди через 1 секунду, а можем и через 1 час. Расскажите по подробней, что за номер и как вы его хотели использовать?

Comment: фыввааапвав

Comment: @bigzhuk  http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/multi/ посмотрите этот параметр.